# CI/CD started failing without a reason. Can it be a month minute limit problem?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I have next error:
[image]

Can it be linked with CI/CD minute limit for gitlab? Or if my limit is out which message should I get?
[image]

Im confused because before everything was working fine without any errors and without any changes in code etc. I just started facing with that issue.

Comment: The answers like "Your tests just are running more that 1hour" are not suitable, because that's 5-10 minutes tests

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of job time? It's certainly odd that you would get a 1hr timeout error if it's only a few minutes long

Comment: The error itself is stating that job is running longer than 1 hour. Even tho your commented your tests run 5-10 minutes, what could happen is that your runner resources could be used to such a point, it takes the execution way longer than you expect it to be. 

Without any additional information as @Arty-chan said about the job status, actual time it took to execute there is not much information to be given to help you.

We had issue where we ran 4 parallel builds and in the end sum of used memory was more than system could handle and all 4 jobs took over an hour (from usual 7-8min each).